# C# to fill out InfoPath Form programmatically?

Tags: c#, automation, infopath

Is it possible to fill out an infopath form and submit it via a C# console application?

If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create a XML file within your C# application and push it to your Sharepoint Form Library. Sharepoint won't realize any difference.

Just ensure two things:

- Your XML must validate against the Infopath **schema**.
- Remember to add the XML **processing instructions**, so that Sharepoint and Infopath know how to handle the XML file. (Simply 'steal' it from an Infopath generated XML.)

Answer (score 0):

MrFox is right, an Infopath Form is just an Xml document that conforms to certain rules, so as long as you create the text file with the correct Xml markups, then you've created an Infopath doc. There are, however, programmatical ways to manipulate a document using the Infopath space. In particular, you can create a new Infopath document from an Infopath template. Lookup more information on `XDocuments2.NewFromSolution()` to see some examples.

Answer (score 0):

- Identify field names and their XML representation
- Read InfoPath form  item from InfoPath document Library
- Load  attached InfoPath form’s XML representation  to XmlTextReader
- Read each node using XmlTextReader and extract user input  based on our requirement